# Display groupname and count in view

Tags: php, eloquent, foreign-keys, laravel-blade, laravel-5.4

I have a difficulty in displaying a school name and its number of students inside the view or blade. I have a 2 tables which are `schools` and `students` 
I have to display the number of students from that school. 
Schools table: `school_id`, `school_name`, `lat`, `lng` 
Students table : student_id, fname, lname, bday, school_id

I want to display something like this

```
[name of school1] : [count of students] 
[name of school2] : [count of students] 
[name of school3] : [count of students] 
[name of school4] : [count of students]
```

Using the eloquent `hasMany` relationship

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Well in your controller you can do something like this:

```
public function index() {
  $schools = School::all()

  return view ('schools.index', compact('schools'));     //ofc change the names of the views and such as you like
}
```

And once in your view you can do this:

```
@foreach($schools as $school)
    School: {{$school->name}} : {{$school->students()->get()->count()}} Students.
@endforeach
```

Hopefully this should work.

**EDIT**

If the count part did not work try it out like this

```
{{$school->count('students')}}
```